# cryptojs TDES convert to OPENSSL

Tags: javascript, openssl, cryptojs, 3des

I write this code in `nodejs` for decrypt `459508BB6B65C5A304D3EFB133038A14` with `TripleDES`:

```
C = require("crypto-js");
text = C.enc.Hex.parse("459508BB6B65C5A304D3EFB133038A14");
key = C.enc.Hex.parse("90033E3984CEF5A659C44BBB47299B4208374FB5DC495C96");
iv = C.enc.Hex.parse("E6B9AFA7A282A0CA");

var d = C.TripleDES.decrypt(
    {
        ciphertext: text
    }, 
        key,
    {
        iv: iv,
        mode: C.mode.CBC
    }
);
var r = d.toString(C.enc.Utf8);
console.log(r);
```

and now i want decrypt this with `OpenSSL` on command line. i try this command but not working:

```
echo -n 459508BB6B65C5A304D3EFB133038A14 | openssl enc -des3 -d -K 90033E3984CEF5A659C44BBB47299B4208374FB5DC495C96 -iv E6B9AFA7A282A0CA -nopad
```

this command not work and return bad decrypted text

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I don't know how I missed that. I wish I could blame the migration, but I can't come up with any plausible theory. Fixed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to hex decode the ciphertext itself, try:

```
echo -n 459508BB6B65C5A304D3EFB133038A14 | xxd -p -r | openssl enc -des3 -d -K 90033E3984CEF5A659C44BBB47299B4208374FB5DC495C96 -iv E6B9AFA7A282A0CA
```

Here `xxd` performs the hexadecimal decoding, using:

> ```
> -p | -ps | -postscript | -plain
>      output in postscript continuous hexdump style. Also known as plain hexdump style.
> -r
>      reverse operation: convert (or patch) hexdump into binary.
> ```

Then it prints out 12 characters, including a space character at the end:

```
1 0 6 4 0 3
```

Note that I also removed `-nopad` as it is not required anymore; crypto-js uses OpenSSL compatible padding (well, openssl compatible *everything* really).